# Need to replace one cursor of a set; have already created the PNG for the cursor

Tags: png, xcursor

I have created a replacement for xterm cursor that will allow me to see the cursor (Windows, incidentally, calls the xterm cursor the "i-beam", which is rather more descriptive) much better. Problem is, I've yet to be able to correctly convert the PNG to the xcursor format. Anyone know what I can do here?

OS: Linux Mint 17.3 (Ubuntu-based; understands Debian packages)

Comment: That's referring to the `pointerShape` resource in xterm (moved by the mouse), by the way.  "Cursor" is used to refer to the text-cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Use **xcursorgen** from the `xorg-x11-apps` or `x11-apps` package to create an Xcursor file from a collection of PNG images.

```
xcursorgen config-file output-file
```

where the config-file has a line with your cursor's

```
size xhot yhot filename
```